# How to sort an array in Ruby by Points? Which is more performant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following hash being created in my Rails controller:

```
myObject = []
....
users.each do |u|
  myObject << {
    user_id: u.id,
    display_name: u.display_name,
    points: u.logs.sum(:points)
  }
end
```

How can I sort myObject by points, High > Low?

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the title you ask "How to sort a hash in Ruby". In the question, you write "I have the following hash …". But in the last sentence, you ask "how can I sort `myObject`", but `myObject` is an array, not a hash. So, are you asking about sorting a hash or an array? In addition, it would also help if you could explain why you weren't able to find your answer in the Ruby documentation, that way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`sort_by!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21) on your `myObject` array:

```
myObject = []

users.sort_by { |user| user }.each do |u|
  myObject << {
    user_id: u.id,
    display_name: u.display_name,
    points: u.logs.sum(:points)
  }
end

myObject.sort_by! { |user| user[:points] }
```

If you want in reverse order, call [`reverse!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse-21):

```
myObject.sort_by! { |user| user[:points] }.reverse!
```

Alternatively, you can sort it by using [`sort!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort-21):

```
myObject.sort! do |user1, user2|
  user2[:points] <=> user1[:points]
end
```

Change the order of the compared objects if you want it in reverse order:

```
myObject.sort! do |user1, user2|
  user1[:points] <=> user2[:points]
end
```

Comment: The only way to know which is more performant when ran on your computer with your dataset is to run it on your computer with your dataset and see which one is more performant. Also, you should define "more performant", what do you mean? Throughput? Latency? Cold-cache? Warm cache? Steady state? Jitter?

Comment: Using `sort!` ends up sorting in the wrong direction, from low to high, where I want High to low

Comment: so follow it with `reverse!`

Comment: @AnApprentice Using `sort!` is probably the fastest way. If you meed to reverse the order, hacnge the order of `user1` and `user2`.